# Automatic generation of Sequence Diagram from code

Tags: c++, automation, c, diagram, uml

Is there a tool to generate sequence diagram of C code by simply passing the package which contain C file.

I tried PlantUML, there i need to right some code to generate sequence diagram(flow diagram). i want to find any tool where there is no need of writing code as the files in the package is very large.

Please recommend me some tool if there is any.

Comment: The eclipse ide has some UML tools, I know they can generate stub code, not sure about dealing with and mapping existing code

Comment: The `doxygen` tool will do the desired output.  Note: you do need to add the necessary `doxygen` statements to the code